# How to return the whole string and extract a column from it in Python?

Tags: python, regex

For example, from this output, I need the string with word 'test1.txt' and then I need the third column from this string, the file size.
Something like "cut" command in Linux

```
5636335  -rw-        1922  Apr 20 2019 09:22:47 +00:00  private-config.cfg
5636332  -rw-        1136  Apr 20 2019 09:22:47 +00:00  NETMAP
5636336  -rw-        0     Apr 20 2019 13:14:51 +00:00  test1.txt
5636325  -rw-        1691  Apr 20 2019 09:22:47 +00:00  startup-config.cfg
5636333  -rw-       16384  Apr 20 2019 09:22:47 +00:00  nvram_00001
5636330  -rw-         341  Apr 20 2019 09:22:47 +00:00  ubridge.log

NETMIKO module
net_connect = ConnectHandler(**cisco)
output = net_connect.send_command('dir')
x = re.search('test1.txt', output)
print(x)

<re.Match object; span=(215, 224), match='test1.txt'>
```

Comment: show what you have tried so far please

Comment: you can use `row.split(' ')[2]` to get elements in row. or you can use fact that number is between 13-th and 25-th char - `row[13:25].strip()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can slice `[13:25]` and `strip()`

```
output = '''5636335  -rw-        1922  Apr 20 2019 09:22:47 +00:00  private-config.cfg
5636332  -rw-        1136  Apr 20 2019 09:22:47 +00:00  NETMAP
5636336  -rw-        0     Apr 20 2019 13:14:51 +00:00  test1.txt
5636325  -rw-        1691  Apr 20 2019 09:22:47 +00:00  startup-config.cfg
5636333  -rw-       16384  Apr 20 2019 09:22:47 +00:00  nvram_00001
5636330  -rw-         341  Apr 20 2019 09:22:47 +00:00  ubridge.log'''

for row in output.split('\n'):
    if 'test1.txt' in row:
        print(row[13:25].strip())
```

There are many spaces between columns so normal `split(' ')` will create too many empty columns and it may not work but `re.split("\s+")` can do it

```
output = '''5636335  -rw-        1922  Apr 20 2019 09:22:47 +00:00  private-config.cfg
5636332  -rw-        1136  Apr 20 2019 09:22:47 +00:00  NETMAP
5636336  -rw-        0     Apr 20 2019 13:14:51 +00:00  test1.txt
5636325  -rw-        1691  Apr 20 2019 09:22:47 +00:00  startup-config.cfg
5636333  -rw-       16384  Apr 20 2019 09:22:47 +00:00  nvram_00001
5636330  -rw-         341  Apr 20 2019 09:22:47 +00:00  ubridge.log'''

import re

for row in output.split('\n'):
    if 'test1.txt' in row:
        print(re.split('\s+', row)[2])
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
tr -s ' ' <test1.txt | cut -d ' ' -f3
```

---

```
1922
1136
0
1691
16384
341
```

---

```
ts -s | squeeze-repeats
cut -d | delimiter
cut -f | field
```

---

> *I know how to do it in Linux, I need Python help*

```
import re
sizes = [re.split(r"\s+", l)[2] for l in open("test1.txt").readlines()]
# ['1922', '1136', '0', '1691', '16384', '341']
```

Comment: I know how to do it in Linux, I need Python help